# VS2010's Test List Editor functionality in VS2012 (Update)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, visual-studio-2012, specflow

Is it possible to get the same Test List Editor functionality from Visual Studio 2010 in Visual Studio 2012?

What I would like to do is make a set of lists containing the tests I want to run. When running a list, I want to be able to move tests easily from one list to another. This was easy in VS2010, but with the Test Explorer in VS2012 this isn't possible anymore. I am aware of the Categories functionality, but this isn't what I'm looking for. It maybe in essence does pretty much the same thing like the tests in VS2010's Test List Editor, but requires much much more work.

Does anyone know an efficient workaround or plugin or something like that to get the same functionality in VS2012?

//UPDATE

After a few months of not using SpecFlow I picked up another project using SpecFlow. A few things has changed for testing using SpecFlow in VS2012. Now it is possible to get functionality in VS2012 that comes closes to the functionality described in VS2010.
This is what did the trick for me:

- Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 introduced the use of playlists;
- Setting the Test Runner Tool to VisualStudio2012 (Tools -> Options -> Specflow -> General -> Test Runner Tool) gave me te opportunity to run single scenarios by just right-clicking on them and select 'Run Unit Tests';
- Installing the NUnit Test Adapter let VS2012 discover all my SpecFlow Scenario's and got them to show up in the Test Explorer where they can be put into playlists.

I hope that this update will help people who where running into the same problems as I was.

Comment: Nothing out of the box or free.

Comment: This feature has been deprecated and you cannot run tests from this editor. You can read this article Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620884.aspx
Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd286683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am aware of the fact that the Test List Editor is deprecated. That's why I'm asking for an efficient workaround or plugin to get the same functionality. I'm not asking for the Test List Editor itself.

Comment: There seems to be an unit test grouping and filtering feature in the upcoming update to VS2012. It can be downloaded now as a CTP. I don't know if it will help in this scenario or not but worth a look. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/09/12/visual-studio-update-this-fall.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One workaround is to use VS2010 at the same time.  I have found this the best way to get the best of both worlds.

I have my solution open in both VS2010 and VS2012 - I do all of my test creation, debugging and maintenance in VS2010.  Then switch back to VS2012 for the other nice features in VS2012.

This gets around the major shortcomings (IMHO) in the new testing functionality in VS2012 which I have found that include the problem you describe and also:

- Removal of "Create Unit Test..." option (major step back!)
- Very slow performance on launching units test on larger projects (in one of my
  projects this is 100 * slower than VS2010)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read of more people that went back to VS2010 because of the testing functionality. It's a shame that VS2012 is such a step back (or maybe more than one step back) in comparison with VS2010 when you want to create/run tests! I haven't been able to really test te performance yet, but a factor of 100 like you said is a whole lot!

Answer (score 2):

With the Update 2 of Visual Studio they introduced the concept of "[Test Playlist](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2013/03/14/new-unit-test-functionality-in-vs2012-update-2-test-playlist/)". 
This allows you to group your Test easily and is similar to the Test Lists.

You can achieve similar results to what you would achieve using traits but as the link I added mentions:

> the use of playlist is an alternative to use Traits to group test and run only a subset, but the main difference is that a **Trait expresses a real property of the test**, (ex the logical area of the software that got tested, or other attribute such Database to indicate that it needs a test database), while **playlist are primarily meant to group together heterogeneous tests to simplify management**, both for running test and manage them.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the test list editor, right click the solution in the solution explorer, add a .testsettings file to the solution. The .testsettings file should now be visible under a folder called "Solution Items" (directly under the solution). All this is in effort to get this folder to show up in the Solution explorer (not sure offhand how to get this to show up otherwise in VS2012). You should also see a ".vsmdi" file showing up under there. Opening that will cause the test list editor window to popup

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Test list editor by opening the *.vsmdi* file as suggested [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14177098/447356), but it gives you a warning:

> Test List editor is deprecated. You can not run test from this editor

And the run button is missing from the window. So effectively you can only see the test case list. VS2012 as the concept of test categories to meet your needs. More details are available at [Defining Test Categories to Group Your Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286595%28VS.110%29.aspx).